# What foods stave off hunger particularly well during long events?

Tags: event, event-photography

When photographing events, I prefer to minimize the time I spend eating because stuff doesn't stop happening just because I've decided to take a break. I've noticed that sometimes, I feel hungrier after eating a snack than I was before. What foods stave off hunger particularly well when photographing during long events?

Answer (score 3):

You're probably getting hungry quickly again because you're eating simple carbs — sugars and white grains. When I'm out shooting for a long time and know I won't get a break, I usually shove a few protein bars in with my camera gear. Look for ones that are relatively low in sugar — a good general tip is to avoid anything that says "energy!" as that's usually just code for "simple carbs" — maybe useful on a bike ride, but not in this circumstance. (Staying power for being on your feet for a long event is different than sports, an exercise routine, or even a hike!)

Dont forget to also pack water!

Comment: Good points about water and simple carbs, but "complex" carbs can also be a problem for some people. People often think protein will "last" longer than carbs, but many proteins are metabolized to sugar when used for energy, so that isn't necessarily the case.

Comment: Protein bars work better for me than any other compact snack. I've also found being sure to be well hydrated when starting and staying hydrated throughout the day make more difference than any snack.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to aim to avoid long gaps between eating in favour of eating "small and often", and looking to minimize risk during downtime.

I will start the day off with a good breakfast. Usually typical "American Diner" sort of thing [Peanut butter oatmeal, or whole wheat toast with eggs and ham/steak], but it is important to aim for well made food that isn't excessively greasy.

From there I will pack easy to eat snacks, and keep plenty of water on hand.

For snacks I'm specifically looking for things that:
- Are not excessively dry or prone to crumbing
- Do not leave my fingers greasy or covered in sugar
- Do not come in overly loud/crinkly wrappers
- Should not involve excessive volume of packaging
- Needs to be quick and easy to get out, and basically bite sized to eat

[One of my go-tos to make are bite sized bits of sausage/pepperoni tightly wrapped in leafy greens. I also had an insulated and magnetically closed belt pouch that I could store them in with an ice pack.]

For overly long days I typically want something extra beyond just snacks, and usually it ends up being something like a sub that is packed with meat and veg.

- Avoid drippy sauces, overly crumbly cheeses, or 'fancy breads' with flaky crusts or 'extra bits' topping them that are prone to leave a mess
- Avoid excessively strong garlic or spice smells
- Pay attention to your personal diet, and avoid things that give you 'digestive complications'

Plan your day, and schedule quick bio-breaks during low priority points, and ideally during times when someone else can cover for you if at all possible.

Also if possible, try to work your day such that you're not left on your feet the whole time. While not directly food related, being able to rest will help you be less tired and in turn less likely to feel hungry throughout the day. [As a sports photographer, I could sometimes be found lying down on a concrete floor... This offered me the opportunity to capture dramatic low angle shots other photographers weren't getting, but also proved a great way to cool off and rest my feet.]

- Get creative, but stay professional for your field.